# how to understand re.sub("", "-", "abxc") in python

Tags: python, regex

recently, I study python regex, i can't understand some expression

```
# but i think it should be : a-b---c
sub_1 = re.sub("x*", "-", "abxc")    # result is : -a-b-c-

# but i think it should be : a-b-x-c
sub_2 = re.sub("", "-", "abxc")      # result is : -a-b-x-c-

# but i think it should be : ['a', '']
find_all_1 = re.findall("a*", "ab")  # result is : ['a', '', '']

# but i think it should be : ['', '', '']
find_all_2 = re.findall("", "abc")   # result is : ['', '', '', '']
```

Comment: What is unclear?

Comment: It's a very good question IMO.